# php how to extract values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I was able to get some details from my results like this:

```
$result["transaction"];
```

when doing this the follow is displayed:

```
{ "id": "wt13LbKmJ2",
  "location_id": "EYGMFA",
  "created_at": "2017-07-01T07:32:57Z",
  "tenders": 
    [ { "id": "C6xMF",
     "location_id": "MFA",
     "transaction_id": "NvDAOOA9",
     "created_at": "2017-07-01T07:32:57Z", 
    "note": "Offering",
     "amount_money": { "amount": 100, "currency": "USD" },                                       "processing_fee_money": { "amount": 33, "currency": "USD" },
     "customer_id": "14QEJXXM5TX",
     "type": "CARD", 
     "card_details": { "status": "CAPTURED", 
     "card": { "brand": "VI", "last_4": "0000" },
     "entry_method": "ON_FILE" 
    } } ], 
    "product": "EXTERNAL_API" }
```

How can I get my array to only display "100" where it say "amount":100
If I use:

```
$result["transaction"]["id"];
```

it will display only the id but I can't get the amount to display.

Answer (score 1):

`$result['transaction']['tenders'][0]['amount_money']['amount']`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to check ur data and use last line like echo $data->tenders[0]->amount_money->amount;

```
<?php
$string='{ "id": "wt13LbKmJ2", "location_id": "EYGMFA", "created_at": "2017-07-01T07:32:57Z", "tenders": [ { "id": "C6xMF", "location_id": "MFA", "transaction_id": "NvDAOOA9", "created_at": "2017-07-01T07:32:57Z", "note": "Offering", "amount_money": { "amount": 100, "currency": "USD" }, "processing_fee_money": { "amount": 33, "currency": "USD" }, "customer_id": "14QEJXXM5TX", "type": "CARD", "card_details": { "status": "CAPTURED", "card": { "brand": "VI", "last_4": "0000" }, "entry_method": "ON_FILE" } } ], "product": "EXTERNAL_API" }';
$data=json_decode($string);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($string));
echo '</pre>';
echo $data->id.'<br>';
echo $data->tenders[0]->id;
echo $data->tenders[0]->amount_money->amount;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change `$result` **object to array** then fetch the data

do like this

```
 $result=json_decode(json_encode($result,true),true);
```

Then

```
$result['transaction']['tenders'][0]['amount_money']['amount']
```

I thing it will help you.